# Python parentheses mistake (?)

Tags: python, parentheses

When I run this code

```
    from numpy import linspace,arange
    from pylab import plot, show
    T=1.05
    pp=[]
    nn=[]
    for V in arange (1,50):
       P=(8*T)/(3*V-1)-3/(V**2)
       a=((V-1/3)*(8/3)*(V**2))/((8/3)*T*(V**3)-6(V-1/3)**2)
       pp.append(P)
       nn.append(a)
    plot(P,a)
    show()
```

I get:

```
File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\", line 8, in <module>
    a=((V-1/3)*(8/3)*(V**2))/((8/3)*T*(V**3)-6(V-1/3)**2)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

And I don't know why.

Comment: `6(V-1/3)` -> `6*(V-1/3)`

Comment: I'd make a fortune with typoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

Issue is in line -

```
a=((V-1/3)*(8/3)*(V**2))/((8/3)*T*(V**3)-6(V-1/3)**2)
```

You are using `6(V-1/3)` , you need to use - `6*(V-1/3)` , as -

```
a=((V-1/3)*(8/3)*(V**2))/((8/3)*T*(V**3)-6*(V-1/3)**2)
```